# Than replace the function locate in sqlite, how to compare strings?

Tags: android, sql, sqlite

select * FROM contacts WHERE address like ? or ? like address 
or ? like address - ERROR

How to write such a select?

Uses sqlite and android

Comment: ? - incoming value, the string

Comment: And how do you want to match it?

Comment: need to check if the address field is part of my string

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please try with a SQL like this

```
select * from contacts where 'yoursearchstring' like '%' || address || '%'
```

This concaternates the wildcards to the field *address*

Answer (score 0):

what do you want to achive with

```
 address like ? or ? like address
```

I guess you need something like that

```
select * from contacts where address like '%yoursearchstring%'
```

that will find every contact containing *yoursearchstring* in the field address

Answer (score 0):

==edit==
I didn't test this, but please try(let me know the result):
sql: `yourString  LIKE ‘%’||ADDRESS||‘%’`
You may need selectionArgs to escape some SQL characters.

```
  SQLiteDatabase db = ...;
  String[] selectionArgs = new String[]{"yourString"};
  db.rawQuery(
    "SELECT * FROM CONTACTS WHERE ? LIKE ‘%’||ADDRESS||‘%’ ", selectionArgs);
```

Comment: I need to find if the field address is part of my string

Comment: In SQL, || is for concaternate, not +  Sorry.